# how to use image tag

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone help me out in inserting an image in the below function. I've used a json object that returns values for campaignid and campaignname.

```
<script>function searchedCampaigns(data) {
if (data[0].length > 0) {
 var searchcmp = "";
for (var j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
var input = document.createElement("input");
console.log(input.name);
searchcmp += '<input type="checkbox" id=' + data[0][j].campaignId + ' name=' + data[0][j].campaignName + '/>' + 
                **// image to be inserted here**        
+ data[0][j].campaignName + '<br/>'; // value   
}
 $("#newcamp").html(searchcmp);
}}</script>
```

output should be this

[image: output should be this]

I'm getting the checkbox as well as the campaign name. I want the image in between these two.

Answer (score 1):

As simple as this..

```
searchcmp += '<input type="checkbox" id=' + data[0][j].campaignId + ' name=' + data[0][j].campaignName + '/>' + 
             '<img src="'+yourimageurlfromdata+'"/>'+
             'data[0][j].campaignName + '<br/>';
```

Comment: here data returns only campaign id and campaign name.

Comment: So from where you will get image `src`?

Comment: Project
|_
  webpages
  |_
    images
    |_icon.png

this is the structure on my project. 
should i write a function to return the location of the image? if so how to do that ?

Comment: change `'<img src="'+yourimageurlfromdata+'"/>'+` to `'<img src="/images/icon.png"/>'+`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you a code like this one:

```
<input type="checkbox"><img src="Image.PNG">Test</img></input>
```

Also, based on your code, it can be updated like this:

```
searchcmp += '<input type="checkbox" id=' + data[0][j].campaignId + ' name=' + data[0][j].campaignName + '><img src=' + YOUR_URL_LOCATION + ' />' + data[0][j].campaignName + '</input><br/>';
```

Where YOUR_URL_LOCATION, can be in the JSON or somewhere else.

It's going to display something like this:

[image]